# How to add vectors to the columns of some array in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I know that, with package `DataFrames`, it is possible by doing simply

```
julia> df = DataFrame();

julia> for i in 1:3
          df[i] = [i, i+1, i*2]
       end

julia> df
3x3 DataFrame
|-------|----|----|----|
| Row # | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| 1     | 1  | 2  | 3  |
| 2     | 2  | 3  | 4  |
| 3     | 2  | 4  | 6  |
```

... but are there any means to do the same on an empty `Array{Int64,2}` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know how many rows you have in your final Array, you can do it using `hcat`:

```
# The number of lines of your final array
numrows = 3

# Create an empty array of the same type that you want, with 3 rows and 0 columns:
a = Array(Int, numrows, 0)

# Concatenate 3x1 arrays in your empty array:
for i in 1:numrows
    b = [i, i+1, i*2] # Create the array you want to concatenate with a
    a = hcat(a, b)
end
```

Notice that, here you know that the arrays `b` have elements of the type `Int`. Therefore we can create the array `a` that have elements of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the rows of the matrix:

```
A = zeros(3,3)
for i = 1:3
  A[i,:] = [i, i+1, 2i]
end
```

Comment: Your code seems nice but how would I add a 4th column that way? I mean, if I don't know how many columns I'll need, how should I implement this? Thanks

Comment: Hrm... If this were a 1d array you could push! and pop! but those macros don't seem to work for 2d arrays.

Comment: You can't append rows to a array with more than one dimension in Julia. The solution is to store the rows as vectors and then use `vcat` or `hcat` to create a matrix.

Comment: This idea of using `hcat` works almost perfect! I just don't know a better way to treat the initial case except by already starting with vector..

Answer (score 2):

If at all possible, it is best to create your Array with the desired number of columns from the start.  That way, you can just fill in those column values.  Solutions using procedures like `hcat()` will suffer from inefficiency, since they require re-creating the Array each time.

If you do need to add columns to an already existing Array, you will be better off if you can add them all at once, rather than in a loop with `hcat()`.  E.g. if you start with:

```
n = 10; m = 5;
A = rand(n,m);
```

then

```
A = [A rand(n, 3)]
```

will be faster and more memory efficient than:

```
for idx = 1:3
    A = hcat(A, rand(n))
end
```

E.g. compare the difference in speed and memory allocations between these two:

```
n = 10^5; m = 10;
A = rand(n,m);
n_newcol = 10;

function t1(A::Array, n_newcol)
    n = size(A,1)
    for idx = 1:n_newcol
        A = hcat(A, zeros(n))
    end
    return A
end

function t2(A::Array, n_newcol)
    n = size(A,1)
    [A zeros(n, n_newcol)]
end

# Stats after running each function once to compile
@time r1 = t1(A, n_newcol);  ## 0.145138 seconds (124 allocations: 125.888 MB, 70.58% gc time)
@time r2 = t2(A, n_newcol);  ## 0.011566 seconds (9 allocations: 22.889 MB, 39.08% gc time)
```