# Julia Approach to python equivalent list of lists

Tags: arrays, julia

I just started tinkering with Julia and I'm really getting to like it. However, I am running into a road block. For example, in Python (although not very efficient or pythonic), I would create an empty list and append a list of a known size and type, and then convert to a NumPy array:

#### Python Snippet

```py
a = []
for ....
    a.append([1.,2.,3.,4.])

b = numpy.array(a)
```

I want to be able to do something similar in Julia, but I can't seem to figure it out. This is what I have so far:

#### Julia snippet

```
a = Array{Float64}[]
for .....
    push!(a,[1.,2.,3.,4.])
end
```

The result is an n-element `Array{Array{Float64,N},1}` of size (n,), but I would like it to be an nx4 `Array{Float64,2}`.

Any suggestions or better way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add Vectors to the Columns of some Array on Julia?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839265/how-to-add-vectors-to-the-columns-of-some-array-on-julia)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The literal translation of your code would be

```
# Building up as rows
a = [1. 2. 3. 4.]
for i in 1:3
    a = vcat(a, [1. 2. 3. 4.])
end

# Building up as columns
b = [1.,2.,3.,4.]
for i in 1:3
    b = hcat(b, [1.,2.,3.,4.])
end
```

But this isn't a natural pattern in Julia, you'd do something like

```
A = zeros(4,4)
for i in 1:4, j in 1:4
    A[i,j] = j
end
```

or even

```
A = Float64[j for i in 1:4, j in 1:4]
```

Basically allocating all the memory at once.

Comment: Thanks for your input, using hcat/vcat does the trick. The issue with allocating all the memory at once, is I don't know what the length of the first dimension will be; it will grow based on specified conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Does this do what you want?

```
julia> a = Array{Float64}[]
0-element Array{Array{Float64,N},1}

julia> for i=1:3
           push!(a,[1.,2.,3.,4.])
       end

julia> a
3-element Array{Array{Float64,N},1}:
 [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
 [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
 [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]

julia> b = hcat(a...)'
3x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
 1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

It seems to match the python output:

```
In [9]: a = []

In [10]: for i in range(3):
    a.append([1, 2, 3, 4])
   ....:

In [11]: b = numpy.array(a); b
Out[11]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

I should add that this is probably not what you actually want to be doing as the `hcat(a...)'` can be expensive if `a` has many elements. Is there a reason not to use a 2d array from the beginning? Perhaps more context to the question (i.e. the code you are actually trying to write) would help.

Comment: This works too! The main focus is trying to build an array with an unknown  length in the first dimension; assuming no prior knowledge of this before hand. The first dimension of the array will grow based on conditional statements.

Comment: Is there any way to do this for the case where the individual arrays being appended are ND (instead of 1D), *and we do not know N*? The problem is Julia seems to lack a generic "convert lists of lists to ND array" function. So, for example, if the arrays are 2D we need to use `cat(a,dims=3)` at the end, and if the arrays are 3D, we need to use `cat(a,dims=4)`. If you just try to use `hcat(a)` it will always collapse the structure down to 2D, and omitting the `dims` argument to `cat` is an error. The only solution I can see is to use `a = cat(a...,dims=length(size(a[1]))+1)`, not good.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers don't work if the number of loop iterations isn't known in advance, or assume that the underlying arrays being merged are one-dimensional. It seems Julia lacks a built-in function for *"take this list of N-D arrays and return me a new (N+1)-D array"*.

Julia requires a different concatenation solution depending on the dimension of the underlying data. So, for example, if the underlying elements of `a` are vectors, one can use `hcat(a)` or `cat(a,dims=2)`. But, if `a` is e.g a 2D array, one must use `cat(a,dims=3)`, etc. The `dims` argument to `cat` is not optional, and there is no default value to indicate "the last dimension".

Here is a helper function that mimics the `np.array` functionality for this use case. (I called it `collapse` instead of `array`, because it doesn't behave quite the same way as `np.array`)

```
function collapse(x)
    return cat(x...,dims=length(size(x[1]))+1)
end
```

One would use this as

```
a = []
for ...
    ... compute new_a...
    push!(a,new_a)
end
a = collapse(a)
```