# Adding columns to a DataArray in Julia

Tags: julia

Following up [How to add vectors to the columns of some array in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839265/how-to-add-vectors-to-the-columns-of-some-array-in-julia), I would like to have some analogous clarifications for DataArrays.

Let `y=randn(100, 2)`. I would like to create a matrix `x` with the lagged value (with `lags > 0`) of `y`. I have already written a code which it seems is working properly (see below). I was wondering if there is a better way for concatenating a DataArray than the one I have used.

```
  T, n = size(y);
  x    = @data(zeros(T-lags, 0));

  for lag in 1:lags
    x = hcat(x, y[lags-lag+1:end-lag, :]);
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is a specific reason to do otherwise, my recommendation would be to start with your `DataArray` `x` being the size that you want it to be and then fill in the column values you want.

This will give you better performance than if you need to recreate the `DataArray` for each new column, which is what any method for "adding" columns will actually be doing.  It's conceivable that the DataArray package might have some more pretty syntax for it than what you have in your question, but fundamentally, that's what it would still be doing.

Thus, in a simplified version of your example, I would recommend:

```
using DataArrays
N = 5; T = 10;
X = @data(zeros(T, N));
initial_data_cols = 2; ## specify how much of the initial data is filled in
lags = size(X,2) - initial_data_cols
X[:,1:initial_data_cols] = rand(size(X,1), initial_data_cols)  ## First two columns of X are fixed in advance


for lag in 1:lags
    X[:,(lag+initial_data_cols)] = rand(size(X,1))
end
```

If you did find yourself in a situation where you need to add columns to an already created object, you could improve somewhat upon the code that you have by first creating all of the new objects together and then doing a single addition of them to your initial DataArray.  E.g.

```
X = @data(zeros(10, 2))
X = [X rand(10,3)]
```

For instance, consider the difference in execution time, and number and quantity of memory allocations in the two examples below:

```
n = 10^5; m = 10;
A = @data rand(n,m);
n_newcol = 10;

function t1(A::Array, n_newcol)
    n = size(A,1)
    for idx = 1:n_newcol
        A = hcat(A, zeros(n))
    end
    return A
end

function t2(A::Array, n_newcol)
    n = size(A,1)
    [A zeros(n, n_newcol)]
end

# Stats after running each function once to compile
@time r1 = t1(A, n_newcol);  ##  0.154082 seconds (124 allocations: 125.888 MB, 75.33% gc time)
@time r2 = t2(A, n_newcol);  ##  0.007981 seconds (9 allocations: 22.889 MB, 31.73% gc time)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have seen online that the initialisation with @data sometimes is problematic. When is that the case?

Comment: @merch I'm not really certain - I don't work that much with the `@data` macro.  I didn't encounter any problems here.  For more beyond that, though, I would recommend a new question, either on SO or on the github page for the DataArrays package, addressing specifics of the initialization issues you are encountering.  As a rough first shot, though, if you find problems, you could first initialize as an Array and then convert to DataArray.

Comment: is there any penalty to carrying extra columns you don't eventually use?

Comment: @PatrickT Some, but it might or might not matter to you.  Your array will take up more ram if it has more columns than you need.  And, certain computations with it could take more time.  But, if you're not super constrained on those fronts, and if the extra number of columns is small, it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelOhlrogge